# What does "the need of the hour" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I came across this idiom in a title, in association with a noun:

> [noun of a product category] — The need of the hour

What does this mean?

Comment: It's not an "idiom" - just a rather lame pun on [hour of need](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hour+of+need%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Of the hour" is an expression used to indicate "of the present (short) period":

- Man of the hour
- Need of the hour
- etc (?)

It doesn't literally mean an hour, but it does imply a short period of time.

Answer (score 5):

*[Hour](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/hour)* here just means a particular point in time. *The need of the hour* simply refers to some need at some point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Its idiomatic mean  " requirements  at  a  given time" according to RPSC

Comment: What is *RPSC*?

Answer (score 0):

Need of the hour has implication that it needs to be high priority.

Comment: Could you provide any references to back your answer? It's a little low on content.

Comment: Example : for the people who do not know to differentiate between a "your" and a "you're", knowledge of grammar is the need of the hour.

Answer (score -3):

Most essential need or requirement.

Answer (score -3):

"need of the hour" refers to the most recent need or the most pressing need.

Comment: Not really. As has been pointed out in many other answers here, it just means a _current_ need, one that is relevant right now.

Comment: recent- adj. current

Comment: _Most recent_ does not mean the same thing as _current_ does. Nor does _recent_ in most cases, for that matter.

Comment: http://thesaurus.com/browse/recent

Comment: A thesaurus does not give definitions. It gives only the most rudimentary of equivalences. You should try looking at the definitions _and_ usage examples in an actual dictionary. That will tell you that _current_ and _recent_, while occasionally interchangeable, have different basic meanings. And again, _most recent_ and _recent_ do not mean the same thing.

Comment: you should read the page before saying it doesn't give the definition as it does as well as the synonyms . that is why i like that site. it also gives you a link to the dictionary as well to get a more formal definition.

Comment: Then I’m sure you can easily see why _current_ does **not** necessarily mean _most recent_.

Comment: as with any words in the english language none are necessarily the same meaning every time. that being said it could mean just that. that is one reason i love the language. even if you disagree with my answer still doesn't mean it is wrong, as it's the way it's used here in the south. i'll just concede we have differing opinions it could be due to regional/generational gap.